# Dreamweaver cs3

Tags: 12.04

can Dreamweaver cs3 be loaded into Ubuntu 12.04.3. with AMD phenom 9150e quad-core processor
When trying to load the CD it says "An error occurred while loading the archive"

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is a Windows Application which you are trying to install on Ubuntu (Linux). With that you may need to use Wine. However, trying to install DW CS3 packaged in Wine will most likely fail as it is marked as Garbage in the [WineHQ Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=183). Your best bet in using DW is by using DW CS4.

Also, since you are using Ubuntu, why not try [Bluegriffon](http://www.bluegriffon.org/)?